# forward syslog to remote server

Tags: linux, rsyslog

On my machine rsyslog.conf i have added

```
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none;auth.none;kern.none;local0.none        <remote host>;RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
lpr.emerg;lpr.!emerg    <remote host>;RSYSLOG_TraditionalForwardFormat
```

On remote server rsyslog.conf i have added

*.emerg /export/ramdisk2/emerg.log;RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

I logged a user.emerg log on native machine using logger command.

I'm not getting log in emerg.log of remote server

Edit:
If i remove negation part it works fine

```
lpr.emerg    <remote host>;RSYSLOG_TraditionalForwardFormat
```

Comment: Your filters are negating each other -- you're saying  to send all `lpr.emerg` but also to ignore everything `lpr` with priority equal-to or higher-than `emerg`.

Comment: Yes i'm doing intentionally bcz *.info is already forwarding emerg severity logs to remote server.